# jquery image-map resizing

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote this function to readjust the location of the  elements onLoad and should the user resize their browser window. It works correctly onLoad but doesn't recalculate correctly when he window is resized.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var orig_width = jQuery("#imageMaps").attr("width");    

        function sizing() { 

              var pic = jQuery('#imageMaps');

              var curr_width =  pic.width();      

              if (orig_width > curr_width) {    
                var width_ratio = orig_width / curr_width;
              }

              else if (orig_width < curr_width) {
                  var width_ratio = curr_width / orig_width;
              }

              var width_ratio_dec = parseFloat(width_ratio).toFixed(2);        alert(width_ratio_dec);

            jQuery("area").each(function() {
            var pairs = jQuery(this).attr("coords").split(', ');
            for(var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
                var nums = pairs[i].split(','); 
                for(var j=0; j<nums.length; j++) { 
                    if (orig_width > curr_width) {
                        nums[j] = nums[j] / width_ratio_dec; 
                    }
                    else if (orig_width < curr_width) {
                        nums[j] = nums[j] * width_ratio_dec; 
                    }
                    else if (orig_width == curr_width) {
                        nums[j]
                    }

                }
                       pairs[i] = nums.join(',');
            }
            jQuery(this).attr("coords", pairs.join(', '));
            }); 
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(sizing);
        jQuery(window).resize(sizing);
```

This is the html:

```
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-430" id="imageMaps" src="SItePlan.gif" width="1500" height="1230" alt="Toledo Beach Marina Map" usemap="#flushometer" border="0" />

<map name="flushometer" id="flushometer"> 

<area shape="circle" coords="515,313,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="910,115,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="948,130,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="1013,126,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="928,375,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="1252,339,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="434,638,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="761,684,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="462,744,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="361,790,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="341,802,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="310,827,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="721,774,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="835,799,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="784,813,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="793,865,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="880,864,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="1033,872,11" href="#" alt="" />
<area shape="circle" coords="444,367,11" href="#" alt="" />

</map>
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(curr_width);` just after setting the variable (when the browser resizes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are resizing the image at the same time as the window resizes.  If not then this is pointless code, but this is a tidied and (I believe) working version of what you posts...

```
var orig_width = 0;

function sizing() { 
    if (orig_width == 0) return;

    var pic = $('#imageMaps');
    var curr_width =  pic.width();      
    var ratio = curr_width / orig_width;

    $("area").each(function() {

        var pairs = $(this).attr("coords").split(', ');

        for(var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {

            var nums = pairs[i].split(','); 

            for(var j=0; j<nums.length; j++) { 
                nums[j] = nums[j] * ratio; 
            }

            pairs[i] = nums.join(',');
        }
        $(this).attr("coords", pairs.join(","));
    }); 
    orig_width = curr_width;
}

$("#imageMaps").one("load", function() {
    orig_width = $("#imageMaps").attr("width");    
    $(window).resize(sizing);
}).each(function() {
    if (this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Note that I only use `ratio`, as you don't need to know if the image is larger or smaller than it was - it's just different or it's the same (ratio == 1).

The only other thing worth noting is that it `sets orig_width = curr_width` after running so that it works out the ratio from the image's current size, not its original size next time there's a resize event.

Comment: Thank you, but this only works after a resize but not onLoad.

Comment: I got this to work by adding: jQuery(document).ready(sizing);

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the calculations for ratio are based on the original width of the img, while the recalculation of the coords are based on the current coords.  You should capture the original coords (maybe in a multi-dimensional array) to be checked against, or reset the size of orig_width after you change your sizing and mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The window resize event will not resize the image. It would seem that onWindowResize you would want to resize the image and then plot the points with their new calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This piggy-backs off the answer that [Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) provided.

In my case I needed to not only resize the image map, but also resize the image to match the container at the same time. I did this by matching the size of the div that contained the image.

```
//resize image map on jobs page
        var mapWidth = $("div#main").width();

        $("#imageMaps").one("load", function() {
            orig_width = $("#imageMaps").attr("width");   
            $("#imageMaps").attr("width", mapWidth);
            sizing();
        }).each(function() {
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
```