# html dynamic map/area tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the map tag on an image that's width and height is set to fill the window. If the user resizes the window, how can I make sure the coordinates map out like they should? I will be using jQuery 1.7, and I want to support all major browsers with IE support from 7+ if that matters.

Comment: It may be simpler to divide your image and calculate their width/height depending on the screen size, then you won't have to solve the map problem.

Comment: yeah, you are probably right. for academical thought, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117219/jquery-image-map-resizing

It may be the same problem